# How can I join 2 objects when objectB enter in objectA' s collider? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

ObjectB can move on player' s command and all the times it interacts with the other object's collider it has to get attach to the latter. Each of the object at the moment have a rigidbody2D and a collider.
Here' s what I' ve tried:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
    if (col.tag == "object2") {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rb.Sleep ();
        GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("object2");
        Vector3 pos = object2.transform.position;
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this seems not to work, as if it keeps to be ignored.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @mjwills Like I said, in the scene this script in totally ignored. Should the above code work?

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint on the if statement, and debug the code, does it hit the breakpoint?